# yum is not working after python update

Tags: python-3.x

yum is not working. Getting the below error.

```
-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/local/bin/python2: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Before steps

1. I did update python 2.6 to 3.3.3.
2. And I set the link : `]# ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.3 /usr/bin/python`
3. `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python` after that it's python version
4. `python -V Python 3.3.3`
5. After that, I tried to use "yum" and got the error

Comment: You should not change the symbolic of python on a linux machine if it rely on python2.7 to work (`ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.3 /usr/bin/python`). This might break some important feature, like the Terminal.

Comment: You are still using python2 to call yum. Use python3 and be sure to install yum on the new ditribution with `pip`

Comment: Thanks for you are reply. I roleback to 2.6. Then how to upgrade python 3+ after installation.